# Maven failing to download jar dependencies and Not show Maven Dependency under libs folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, download

I have create new maven project by choosing org.apache.maven.archtypes maven.archtype.webapp.

I perfom this commands,

- pom right click maven clean
- pom right click maven install.
- I checked maven user setting file
- project right click maven update.

but maven dependency library is not added into libraries folder Although I have taken build success message.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
<p> 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] Total time: 2.248 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-07T09:40:57+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
```

added my pom file. E.g dependecy mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache. rg/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven.test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>maven.test Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is Fault screen shot
[image: my library screen shots as u can see without maven dependecy]

**My temporary solution:**

**but new java project and convert to maven project this is work when perfom this way maven dependency is showing**